# Pulling Data from App Annie API - Python

Tags: python, appannie

I need to pull some data from App Annie's API using Python.   However I am unable to connect.  I double checked my API key and the "documentation".  Does anyone know how I can connect through their API?  I keep getting a 401 unauthorized access error.

https://support.appannie.com/hc/en-us/articles/204208864-3-Authentication

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://api.appannie.com/v1.2/apps/ios/app/12345678/reviews?start_date=2012-01-01&end_date=2012-02-01&countries=US'
key = 'Authorization: bearer b7e26.........'

response = requests.get(url, key)    #After running up to this I get 401

data = json.loads(response.json())  #data is a dictionary
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify your api key in the HTTP header:

```
response = requests.get(url,
                        headers={'Authorization':'bearer b7e26.........'})
```

Comment: Where does the username and password have to be specified when making the API call?  I am trying this solution but get a 401 unauthorized access error.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer and not a question. I put my answer under comment by mistake.

(General information. Hopefully it helps out).
Calling the API key in the header: it worked for me when I added a space after `:` and before `bearer` and between `bearer` and `API KEY`:

`'Authorization': 'bearer API KEY'`

Do not use the app name. **YOU NEED THE APP ID**.

Steps for app id:

1. Select the app.
2. Click App info.
3. Scroll to the very bottom of page and look under the scroll bar.
   The app id verbiage/text is a very light gray color.
4. Click copy and use the app id. (Using the app name will throw a 401, 403, or a 404 error.)
   Make sure you dump data into a json or it will throw a 200 error. I was receiving a 200 error while I was just trying to print the data without dumping it into json.